# Deleting from a BST in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am very new to C programming and am using it for one of my classes. The project I am working on involves a BST and deleting nodes from it.

In terms of memory and allocation, if all the nodes in the tree are created using malloc() function, is it enough to call free on a particular node to delete it? Or do I have to set the pointer from the parent to NULL as well?

Comment: Calling `free` is sufficient to free the memory, but if you don't set the pointer from the parent to null, then how will you know that there's no longer a node in that position?

Comment: Would I call free and then set pointer to NULL or set the pointer to NULL and then call free?

Comment: If you set the pointer to `NULL` before you call `free` you have a memory leak because the pointer information is lost. How would `free` know what to deallocate?

Answer (score -1):

A pointer which points to nothing will by default have a value of NULL, so I don't see why you'd need to manually set it.  It wouldn't hurt anything, but freeing the memory would be sufficient.

You can always write a quick test to make sure that the value of the now non-existent child is in fact NULL... something like this (not tested, just a general idea):

```
int checkNull(Node* x){
    return(x->child == NULL ? 1 : 0);
}
```

If checkNull() returns 1, you're good.  If not, maybe you do have to manually reset it after all.  Hope this helps.

Comment: "A pointer which points to nothing will by default have a value of NULL" -- not the case at all.

Comment: Usually a NULL pointer is used exactly to show that it points to nothing. But of course, it has to be set (i.e. initialized) to that value in general